# Missing number, treated as zero error when using for loops and conditionals in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, ifthenelse

I would be nice to be able to have a code that, by modifying certian parameters like height and width and cells to be colored red or green, generates a table for me. The code I have is already a modification of something I found, but I can't get the colored cells to work. The error is "Missing number, treated as zero." I am just starting out in tikz and don't understand much.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
[
    square/.style = {
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        minimum size=\m, 
        outer sep=0, 
        inner sep=0, 
        font=\normalsize\bfseries,
        label={[anchor=north,yshift=1.1em,opacity=0.7]south:\scriptsize\label}
    },
]
\def\m{35pt}
\def\w{4}
\def\h{4}

% Array of personalized messages
\def\content{{
    {1, 0, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1}
}}

% Separate arrays for x and y coordinates in greenCoords
\def\greenXCoords{{1, 1, 1, 1}} % x-coordinates
\def\greenYCoords{{1, 2, 3, 4}} % y-coordinates

% Y
\foreach \x in {1,...,\w}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
    {   
        % Check if the current coordinates match any green cells
        \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        {
            \ifthenelse{\x=\greenXCoords[\i] \AND \y=\greenYCoords[\i]}
                {\def\fillColor{green!30}\break}
                {\def\fillColor{black!5}}
        }
        
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
        \node [square, fill=\fillColor]  (Y\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m) {\pgfmathparse{\content[\y-1][\x-1]}\pgfmathresult};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Table obtained]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hi, thanks! Are you referring to me adding the preamble aswell?

Comment: Well, add the used documentclass and the used packages for your code snippet and add `\begin` and `\end{documentclass}` ...

Comment: Ifthenelse doesn't understand the array syntax of PGFMath. You need to extract this beforehand (say via `\pgfmathsetmacro`) or use PGFmath's own conditional function to evaluate it. (Or you use a totally different system for both arrays and conditionals or you create your diagram differently without having to rely on a bunch of arrays.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array syntax `\greenXCoords[\i]` is a [PGFMath syntax](https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#pgf.back/pgfmatharray) and not understood by `\ifthenelse`.

You will need to evaluate these beforehand, say

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\xTest{\greenXCoords[\i]}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yTest{\greenYCoords[\i]}
\ifthenelse{\x=\xTest \AND \y=\yTest}
```

or use PGFMath's own [`ifthenelse` function](https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#pgf.back/pgfmathifthenelse) or use a whole different approach to arrays and conditionals.

Or you construct your table with without having to loop through so many arrays and loops. (A PGFMath array isn't the best data structure.)

---

Here's a solution that loops through the `content` value directly using its own structure (it's already made up of rows and columns).

A few styles and keys and you can construct a table with any content, any size and any combination of green cells.

Here, the number of columns (for the calculation of the label) needs to be provided but there could be solutions that determine this automatically (from the first/longest row?) or just count up for each element which wouldn't create holes if the rows don't have all the same number of columns.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  % let's do this in our own namespace
  my table/.cd,
  % initial values and settings
  content/.initial={{1, 0, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 1, 1, 1}},
  size/.initial=35pt,
  columns/.initial=4,
  square/.style={
    shape=rectangle, draw, minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my table/size},
    outer sep=+0pt, inner sep=+0pt, fill=black!5, font=\normalsize\bfseries},
  label/.style={
    label={[anchor=south, font=\scriptsize, lightgray]south:{#1}}},
  % styles to set which rows, cols and cells should be green!30
  green rows/.style={green row/.list={#1}},
  green cols/.style={green col/.list={#1}},
  green cells/.style={green cell/.list={#1}},
  green row/.style={/tikz/my table/rowstyle #1/.append style={fill=green!30}},
  green col/.style={/tikz/my table/colstyle #1/.append style={fill=green!30}},
  green cell/.style={/tikz/my table/style #1/.append style={fill=green!30}}}

% the macro with one optional (!) argument
\newcommand*\PrintTable[1][]{%
  \tikz[
    my table/.cd,#1,content/.get=\myTableContent,
    % make the xyz coordinate system dependent on the size of your squares
    /tikz/x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my table/size},
    /tikz/y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my table/size}]
  \foreach[count=\myTableY from 0,
           count=\myTableYY from 1]\myTableRow in \myTableContent
    \foreach[count=\myTableX]\myTableCol in \myTableRow
      \node[
        my table/square,
        my table/label=\inteval{\myTableY*
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my table/columns}+\myTableX},
        my table/rowstyle \myTableYY/.try,        % 1. row style
        my table/colstyle \myTableX/.try,         % 2. col style
        my table/style \myTableYY-\myTableX/.try, % 3. cell style
      ] at (\myTableX,-\myTableY) {\myTableCol};%
}
\begin{document}
\PrintTable[green cells={1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4}]
\PrintTable[green row=1, columns=3, content={{  1,   2,   3},
                                             { 19,  20,  21},
                                             {123, 456, 789}}]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.